# Why must the $gcd((N-1)!,N)=1$ in order to factor out $(N-1)!$ from both sides of $a^{N-1}(N-1)! \equiv (N-1)! \pmod N $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to gain the intuition of why must the $gcd((N-1)!,N)=1$ in order to factor out $(N-1)!$ from  $a^{N-1}(N-1)! \equiv (N-1)! \pmod N $?

Comment: Not complaining about the down vote, however, it would be helpful to know why it was down voted? Is it a stupid question, is it inappropriate, wrong forum, etc?

Comment: Probably because you don't include any context or background info. Where does this problem come from? What have you looked at? What special cases are there?

Comment: @TheCount First, thanks for the comment. The context was this it's part of a proof of Fermat's Little Theorem, however, I'm not sure how that would really help as context. The question was trying to understand the differences, if any, in factoring an equivalence with a modulus. However, five folks including yourself feel it's "off-topic" and so I obviously am in error. Probably best to delete the question, but I'm barred from doing so.

Comment: You should carefully read the off-topic blurb. The question itself is fine, but we need to know more about the motivations, your effort, etc. It any case, it seems you've gotten the help you needed, so food for future thought.

Comment: @TheCount Thanks for the feedback and I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what the congruence means; it means precisely that $N$ divides
$$a^{N-1}(N-1)!-(N-1)!=(N-1)!(a^{N-1}-1).$$
You want to factor out $(N-1)!$, i.e. to conclude that $N$ divides $a^{N-1}-1$. Do you see what the problem is if $\gcd((N-1)!,N)\neq1$?

Comment: Definitely see it thanks to you. Your answer clears up what was probably an obvious answer...just not to me :)